# R code - How can I manipulate the df below to look like this this:

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, row, multiple-columns

Currently I wrote this code:

```
lc <- round(tabyl(x$Likelihood.to.Click,  show_na = FALSE),2)
lc$percent <- lc$percent * 100
```

and produced this chart:

[image]

But In need help manipulating it to create the below df (basically its summing the percentages
of row 1 and 2, leaving 3 as is, and then summing 4 and 5:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make your example reproducible using `dput(lc)` to pass the data:

```
lc <- structure(list(L2E = 1:5, n = c(7, 23, 84, 73, 33), pct = c(3, 
10, 38, 33, 15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Now define the groups

```
groups <- list(1:2, 3, 4:5)
sumpct <- sapply(groups, function(x) sum(lc[x, 3]))
lc2 <- data.frame(group=seq(length(groups)), sumpct)
lc2
#   group sumpct
# 1     1     13
# 2     2     38
# 3     3     48
```

Note that row 3 is 38, not 32 and in rows 4 and 5, 33 + 15 = 48, not 54.